# UITextView emoji background issue

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextview, emoji

I have an `UITextView` extension with emoji enabled and when I switch to the emoji keyboard the emoticons have a white background. I tried to update the `UITextView` background color, I removed the custom attributes from my extension and I also used a default `UITextView` but the white background is always there. When I click on an emoticon it is correctly shown into the `UITextView` without the white background. What could be the cause of this?

This is the screenshot of the soft keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this. I post this here in case someone has the same problem. I was setting

```
UICollectionViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
```

Because the appearance was set globally and the keyboard emoticons are of type `UICollectionViewCell`, the white background was shown for each cell.

Since I have a custom extension for my UICollectionViewCells, I changed the previous line to

```
MyCollectionViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
```